# Send SMS iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sms, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I was trying to send SMS from within my app. I wrote this piece of code but it seems not to work.
No crash, no error log, simply nothing happen (of course I tried to log `canSendText` and the result is `1`).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    messageComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        [messageComposer setBody:@"Messaggio generato da SMSTest"];
        [messageComposer setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"3333333333"]];
        [messageComposer setDelegate:self];

        [self presentModalViewController:messageComposer animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you test it on the simulator? Simulator cann't send SMS.

Comment: you are trying to do this while running the app on the phone and not on the simulator, right?  You won't be able to send sms from sim.  I don't think it throws any errors for that either... though I can't recall that for sure.

Comment: Yes I tried on the iPhone. As I said, `canSendText` returns 1. In the simulator it would returns 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `presentModalViewController` does not work in `viewDidLoad` yet as the view is loaded but might not even be on screen yet. If you put your code in `viewWillAppear:animated`, this should work.

Edit: As per Saphrosit's comment: `viewDidAppear:` is an even better place to do this.

Comment: Very good point, but even in `viewWillAppear` the view might not be on the screen yet. It worked putting the code in `viewDidAppear`, even if the best solution is to use a button to execute a custom method.

Answer (score 0):

I use this successfully:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Note that it's messageComposeDelegate, not 'delegate' as you do.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

When i try the code on simulator i get an UIAlert saying text messaging is not available, because simulator can´t send messages. Have you checked that your header file is a delegate of MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate ?

```
YourClassName : UIViewController  <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this ... it will run ..

> ```
> MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
>       if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
>       {
>           controller.body = @"Hello from Kartik";
>           controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12356478", nil];
>           controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
>           [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
>       }
> ```